# Create node and node reference from URL at one time

Tags: 7, nodes

I have content type "article", in some cases I need to orginise group of parent and child nodes and to do this I use Node Reference from URL module. Also I need to include parent node in this group of articles because some views and node URL depend on completed field "node reference". So, how it works now:

1. I create a parent node and leave the node reference field empty as the parent node doesn't exist now;
2. Save this node
3. Back to edit page and choose my new parent node from the list of avalible nodes in node reference field;

What I would like to do is to create parent node and fill node reference field at the same time.

I guess that Rules module could help me but It too powerfull module and I do not need it for my website. Is there a more simple solution?

Comment: Why can't you create parent node first?

Comment: yes, I do that at first but I need to have filled node reference field filled with the link to itself. I mean that if parent node "Node 1" the node reference field have the same value "Node 1" it should not be empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `hook_node_insert` and update the node.

Comment: OP is not using Drupal 6

Comment: @NikhilM which OP?

Comment: OP one who originally posted the question.

Comment: oh ya ya.. it is different function in 7... sorry but I think he can understand what I want to say.

Comment: I changed it now.. thnx..

Comment: thank you for your idea, what I particular used: `function custom_module_node_presave($node) {
  $node->field_add[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['nid'] = $node->nid;
}`

Comment: but now I need to put a condition in this function, to use this presave only if field if empty

Comment: Did you get the nid in `presave`? And you can make a condition check,  `if(!isset($node->field_add[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['nid'])){$node->field_add[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['nid'] = $node->nid;}`

Comment: yes, it was my mistake it worked as I tried on existing nodes that already have nid..

Answer (score 5):

Depending on which relationship module you're using there are different options.

- If you're using [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) there's the [Inline Entity Form](http://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module:

  > Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification, removal) of referenced entities.
  >   The primary use case is the parent -> children one (product display -> products, order -> line items, etc.), where the child entities are never managed outside the parent form.
- If you're using the [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module there's [References Dialog](http://drupal.org/project/references_dialog):

  > This module extends reference fields like the user and node reference fields by adding links to add, edit and search for references through a dialog. This allows for a workflow where the user can create all the references to a node at the same time as she is creating it, a process which sometimes get's a bit backwards, when a user for instance needs to create all the facts for an article.

Both will allow you to create a referenced node at the same time as creating the referee.